# Change button text when bool value changes

Tags: javafx

I have a class which extends Button. There is a static boolean which is set to false. I want to change the text of all the buttons when this boolean changes value to true.

I tried playing with the bind feature but failed. :D

```
public class KolonaA extends Button{
    ...
    static Boolean solved = false;
    ...
    public KolonaA() {
    super();
    this.setPrefSize(size[0], size[1]);
    this.setLayoutX(xCord + buttonCount * 30);
    this.setLayoutY(yCord + buttonCount * 40);

    //something like this:
    this.textProperty().bind(solved ? "true" "false"); 
    //CHANGE TEXT OF BUTTON WHEN solved CHANGES VALUE
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `I want to change the text of all the buttons` - I can see only one button.

Comment: I meant all the instances of this class, since I'm creating 5 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure if it is for just one button and a set of buttons. If you want to change the text of the custom button for which you have posted the code, instead of a Boolean, use a `BooleanProperty`. Later you can add a `Listener` to it and change the text of the Button accordingly.

```
public class KolonaA extends Button{
    ...
    public BooleanProperty solved = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    ...
    public KolonaA() {
        super();
        solved.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if(newValue)
                    setText("True");
                else
                    setText("False");
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```